# How to get the data from android?

Tags: android

I am storing the string values **in arraylist** in **Select.java** page. Now I need to get those string values into other page i.e **review.java** page. How to do that? Please help me regarding this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either make this  `arraylist as public static` or use `Intent.putStringArrayListExtra();` and pass it to your review.java (If both java class are activity).

something like,

In Select.java

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Select.this, review.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("stock_list", stock_list);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and In review.java

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
stock_list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("stock_list");
```

Here stock_list is a String ArrayList...

You can also use `Intent.putExtra("keyName", "somevalue");` for passing ArrayList..

Comment: hi thank you..I have used public static and sent the values...

Comment: @user370305:Hello,maybe you could help me here?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703103/android-make-calculations-with-input-data-show-graphs

Answer (score 2):

You can use Extras to pass data to an activity when you start it. An example is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, review.class);
intent.putExtra("YOUR_DATA_KEY", arrayListVar);
startActivity(intent);
```

check out the "Extras" section of the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) for more info. This is the preferred method of sharing information across activities (you shouldn't use public variables since that would introduce a dependency between your two activities when all they really need to depend on is data).

Answer (score 0):

Declare this in your Select.java

static String[] x=new String[]{"a","b","c"}; globally. Making them static can get you access in other class.

in review.java create object static Select dd and static Select[] all;

dd = new Select("a","n","m");
all[i]=dd;