# android -- how to deal when pressing buttons and taking results -- updated-->buttons don't responds

Tags: android, button

I want in the first screen to have two buttons and when the user clicks one of them ,then he will go to another screen with other buttons.I am not sure how to handle this.

My main class is :

```
public class Radiation extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
View num_cores;
View num_mass;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
    //Set up click listeners
    num_cores=(View) findViewById(R.id.select_cores);
    num_cores.setOnClickListener(this);
    num_mass=(View) findViewById(R.id.select_mass);
    num_mass.setOnClickListener(this);
}

//called when a button is clicked
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.num_cores:
        Intent i=new Intent(this,number_cores.class);
        startActivity(i);  
        break;
    case R.id.num_mass:
        Intent k=new Intent(this,number_mass.class);
        startActivity(k);  
        break;
}
}
```

}

When i press the num_cores button the user goes to another screen and there inputs some data in an edit text field and a calculate button does the calculation and then the result is shown.

Here is the number_cores.class :

```
public class number_cores extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText num_cores;
View core_calcs;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.numbercores);
    
    num_cores=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.num_cores);
    core_calcs=(View) findViewById(R.id.core_calcs);
    core_calcs.setOnClickListener(this);
  
}

  
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.core_calcs:
            cores_func();
            break;
    
        }
      }
        public void cores_func(){
         //some calculations here with result "double fcores=.."
           Intent i=new Intent(this,core_calcs.class);
           i.putExtra("value",fcores);
          startActivity(i);  
       }
  }
```

the core_calcs.java:

```
public class core_calcs extends Activity {
    
    TextView corecalcs;

    
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.core_calcs);
              
        corecalcs=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.corecalcs);
        double f=getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("value");
        corecalcs.setText(Double.toString(f));
        
    }
    
}
```

the same goes for the other button.

How can i handle this?I am lost in my buttons!Is there a more efficient way?
(Right now,my application doesn't run)

--UPDATED ---------------

I hadn't defined the buttons width in my main.xml that's why the program crashed.

Now, it gives me the first screen with my two buttons but nothing happens when i click them.

Comment: please update your question to include the crash stack trace. Whenever your application crashes you should probably post the stack trace to see what's the cause. It would make it easier to help you with your issues (or even for you to understand what went wrong)

Comment: What do you mean by being lost? I guess you're having a problem in naming your ids, so you should set yourself some conventions (for instance, every id of a Button begins with "btn_" and every id of a TextView with "txt_" and so on).
If you post your stack trace we can try to help you more regarding the crashing issue.

Comment: You mean the logcat?Because there it has a lot of things.

Comment: @jcxavier : I updated,now the buttons don't respond..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was in the

```
public class Radiation extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
View select_cores;
View select_mass;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Set up click listeners
    select_cores=(View) findViewById(R.id.select_cores);
    select_cores.setOnClickListener(this);
    select_mass=(View) findViewById(R.id.select_mass);
    select_mass.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

where i had "View num_cores" i changed to "View select_cores" and now works fine!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you're just taking input from a single EditText field. Using a second Activity can work but is a bit overkill for just doing this task. You may find it easier to use something like a Dialog http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

However this is just another way to approach your question. To answer your question specifically you would use:

Declare this above:

```
private static final int ACTIVITY_RESULT = 0;
```

Use this instead of startActivity(i);

```
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_RESULT);
```

and you can then capture the result using:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_RESULT) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        //Do stuff to captured result.
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am looking sth familiar with my code right now.I have in mind the Dialog but i want to practice with buttons now.